# Sending mail from Third party sites Programmatically

Tags: java, c#, python, .net, email

How can I send mail from sites other than gmail, hotmail, rediffmail. Without any API provided. Is there provision to make this happen in any of programming languages. I think the domain I'm going to use does not have any captcha checks.
I also would like to attach a folder within.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about other domain names, like your own domain then you can use below method:

Add `using System.Net.Mail;`
then below in some event

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.yoursite.com");
                   mail.From = new MailAddress("testing@yoursite.com");
                   mail.To.Add("youremail@address.com");
                   mail.Subject = "New Email";
                   mail.Body = "add text here from controls";

                   SmtpServer.Port = 25;
                   SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("testing@yoursite.com", "passhere");
                   SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
                   SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                   MessageBox.Show("All Done");
```

Comment: Thank you, Is it possile for all domains or my domain only? I want to make it for another domain.

Comment: its upto you how many time you want to trigger this code, but for each individual domain you have to change above settings. for exmaple if you have domain name www.xyz.com then in above change the settings according to that, you have to create an email inside your domain, then add that email and its password in above code. give it a test run. it should work.

Comment: Ok I ll get back to you witha a feedback. Thanks bro